# How to get a property value from a specific property file using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource through Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Consider I've two property files under /WEB-INF/properties/

1.**names.properties**

2.**cities.properties**

These properties have key-value pairs.I want to read **value**s defined in these property files by passing **key** using **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** through Spring.

I've two questions :

1. If both of the properties have a same key, how to tell Spring to get the value from a Specific property file ?

Example : 
names.properties has a key-value pair : key1=James and 
cities.properties has a key-value pair : key1=Bangalore

I want to get value "James" by passing "key1" from "names.properties" and not from any other properties even though the same key is present in other properties.. how to achieve it ?

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
String value = applicationContext.getMessage("key1",
        null, "DefaultValue", null); => there is no way to tell Spring from which property file value should be read ! (not locale)
```

2. I want to refresh property file through code ( Not automatically when file changes). So I've removed `<property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>` from applicationContext.xml.

so applicationContext.xml looks like

```
<bean id="messageSource"    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames" >
<list>
   <value>/WEB-INF/properties/names</value>
   <value>/WEB-INF/properties/cities</value> 
 </list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Refresh properties method looks like :

```
 public static void refreshProperties(final ApplicationContext applicationContext,String propertyFileName) 
 {
      ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource res = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) 
                   applicationContext.getBean("messageSource");
      res.clearCache();
 }
```

But the problem with the above code is it refreshes all the properties which are defined in applicationContext List. How to refresh a specific property file ? Say I want to refresh only "names.properties".

Comment: You should have two different instances of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet . In that case , say If I've 10 property files, I'll have to define 10 different instances of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource !  And also this will solve only Refresh a specific property file problem.. What about getting a property value from a specific property file?

Comment: if you get a message from the first ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean, it will load it from the first properties file. If you get a message from the second ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean, it will get it from the second properties file.

Comment: @JBNizet for getting message,                                     `ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
String value = applicationContext.getMessage("key1",
        null, "DefaultValue", null); ` there is no way to tell Spring which ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean it should return.. or is there any?

Comment: @JBNizet  But as you said , for refresh  a specific property file, we can use your technique                                                                                           `public static void refreshProperties(final ApplicationContext applicationContext,String resourceBundleBeanName) 
 {
      ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource res = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) 
                   applicationContext.getBean(resourceBundleBeanName);
      res.clearCache();
 }`

Comment: Don't get the message from the applicationContext. Get it from the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean: you get the bean (thanks to dependency injection, preferrably, or by looking it up in the application context as you're doing in your last comment), and you ask this bean for the message.

Comment: @JBNizet  Sooperb idea :)   I didn't think in that way. It worked ! Thanks a lot .  If you find any other way (Other than defining n number of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource beans for n number of properies file) please let me know :)